# Unity to Godot: MeshFilter

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I'm working on porting a unity project that I made a while ago over to Godot.

In Unity I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MeshGenerator 
{

    public SquareGrid squareGrid;
    public MeshFilter walls;

    void CreateWallMesh(int[,] map, float squareSize, int tileAmount){
        MeshCollider currentColliders = walls.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        Destroy(currentColliders);
        CalculateMeshOutlines();

        List<Vector3> wallVertices = new List<Vector3>();
        List<int> wallTriangles = new List<int>();
        Mesh wallMesh = new Mesh();
        float wallHeight = 5;

        foreach(List<int> outline in outlines){
            for(int i = 0; i < outline.Count-1; i++){
                int startIndex = wallVertices.Count;
                wallVertices.Add(vertices[outline[i]]); // left vertex
                wallVertices.Add(vertices[outline[i+1]]); // right vertex
                wallVertices.Add(vertices[outline[i]] - Vector3.up * wallHeight); // bottom left vertex
                wallVertices.Add(vertices[outline[i+1]] - Vector3.up * wallHeight); // bottom right vertex

                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 0);
                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 2);
                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 3);

                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 3);
                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 1);
                wallTriangles.Add(startIndex + 0);
            }
        }
        wallMesh.vertices = wallVertices.ToArray();
        wallMesh.triangles = wallTriangles.ToArray();

        MeshCollider wallCollider = walls.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        wallCollider.sharedMesh = wallMesh;

        float textureScale = walls.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTextureScale.x;
        float increment = (textureScale / map.GetLength(0));
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[wallMesh.vertices.Length];
        float[] uvEntries = new float[]{0.5f,increment}; 

        for (int i = 0; i < wallMesh.vertices.Length; i++) 
        {
            float percentY = Mathf.InverseLerp ((-wallHeight) * squareSize, 0, wallMesh.vertices [i].y) * tileAmount * (wallHeight / map.GetLength(0));
            uvs [i] = new Vector2(uvEntries[i % 2],percentY);
        }

        wallMesh.uv = uvs;
        wallCollider.sharedMesh = wallMesh;
        walls.mesh = wallMesh;
    }
```

And I'm getting an error that says

> The type or namespace name 'MeshFilter' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I believe it's referencing this unity mesh, and I'm curious what the correct way to do it in Godot is.

[image]

**Edit:**
In case it helps, what the class does is takes a random 2D map and builds up walls around the area the player is supposed to travel through. Here's a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating a [`Mesh`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_mesh.html) in runtime in Godot see [`ImmediateMesh`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_immediatemesh.html#class-immediatemesh), [`MeshDataTool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_meshdatatool.html#class-meshdatatool) or [`SurfaceTool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_surfacetool.html#class-surfacetool). With any of those you can get a `Mesh` that you can display using a `MeshInstance3D` or for other uses.

*Although `ImmediateMesh` name and interface evoke the old OpenGL immediate mode, it is only an usability façade.*

---

The code suggest you also want a collider. That means you want a `Shape3D` that you can use with a `CollisionShape3D` child of an `Area3D`, `StaicBody3D`, `CharacterBody3D`, `RigidBody3D`... Note: they can have multiple `CollisionShape3D` or `CollisionPolygon3D` children, so you do not need to make a single collider.

The `Shape3D` can be one of the many primitive shapes (e.g. [`BoxShape3D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_boxshape3d.html#class-boxshape3d)), which are the most performant.

Alternatively you can pick between [`ConcavePolygonShape3D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_concavepolygonshape3d.html#class-concavepolygonshape3d) and [`ConvexPolygonShape3D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_convexpolygonshape3d.html#class-convexpolygonshape3d). You can create them from a `Mesh` using [`create_trimesh_shape`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_mesh.html#class-mesh-method-create-trimesh-shape) and [`create_convex_shape`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_mesh.html#class-mesh-method-create-convex-shape) respectively.

*`ConcavePolygonShape3D` is THE WORSE. You have been warned.*

---

See also [`create_convex_collision`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_meshinstance3d.html#class-meshinstance3d-method-create-convex-collision), [`create_multiple_convex_collisions`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_meshinstance3d.html#class-meshinstance3d-method-create-multiple-convex-collisions) and [`create_trimesh_collision`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_meshinstance3d.html#class-meshinstance3d-method-create-trimesh-collision) from `MeshInstance3D`. In particular `create_multiple_convex_collisions` will do decomposition for you.

Be aware that these method will create `StaticBody3D` children of the `MeshInstance3D`. If you do not want `StaticBody3D`, you can always take the colliders, remove them from their parent, and add them where you need them.

---

**Addendum**

After looking at the picture, I believe using CSG nodes this would be easy for you.

CSG stands for Constructive Solid Geometry, it is making boolean operations with 3D shapes.

So you can have a `CSGCombiner3D` with a child `CSGBox3D` for the exterior volume. And then to substract a `CSGPolygon3D` from it, you add it as second child and set its `operation` to `OPERATION_SUBTRACTION`.

To define the `CSGPolygon3D` all you need is to figure out the polygon in 2D since it extends it to 3D using a `depth` you can configure.

Once you have it setup, you can use [`get_meshes`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_csgshape3d.html#class-csgshape3d-method-get-meshes) which gives you an array with a `Transform3D` and a `Mesh` (which you can use in a `MeshInstance3D`, from which you can also generate a physics body as explained above).

Or, alternatively, you can use the CSG nodes directly. Since you can set `use_collision` to `true` to enable physics.

Comment: The basic purpose of the class is to take a map that is created randomly and turn it into a maze like cave or mine that can be walked through.

Comment: @AndyD273 And you want that as a single mesh? And you would have to rewrite the generation of the mesh if you want different features? - Consider instead to populate a `GridMap` procedurally. Edit: After looking the picture, I see what you are doing. Edit 2: Try `CollisionPolygon3D`, or even a `CSGPolygon3D`.

Comment: I added in an example of what the current map could look like in unity. It's random each time it starts. Gridmap appears to lay out map tiles in a grid, which isn't exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I just realized that there is a game development SE... Now I'm wondering if there is a benefit to asking over there instead of here.

Comment: @AndyD273 There is overlap. Stackoverflow takes programming problems, and Gamedev gets game development problems... Which are not just programming, notably they include game design. In general, if a question is on topic on multiple sites, you can post it on whichever you want, so pick where you think it will have the right audience. And please don't cross post. I answer Godot questions over there too, by the way. Addendum: I should point out that Godot has it own [community](https://godotengine.org/community/) sites, and I do not answer there.

Comment: I looked at your profile, which is how I figured out that it existed. I made the unity version a couple years ago, and after unity decided to change their policy and watching the Pirate Games youtube game dev channel I got inspired to try to do it again in Godot, but I think I forgot a lot of what I figured out when I made it the first time. I'll have to read up on those mesh types to see if I can figure out what might work for me.

Comment: @AndyD273 After looking at the picture, I believe using CSG nodes this would be easy for you. You can use a `CSGPolygon3D` for the inside, and substract it from a `CSGBox3D`. All the code you need is to create the polygon in 2D, since the `CSGPolygon3D` extends it with a `depth`. You can then either generate your mesh with a `CSGCombiner3D` or just use the CSG nodes directly (they have an option to enable physics). Addendum: CSG stands for Constructive Solid Geometry, it is making boolean operations with 3D shapes. Addeendum 2: I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: I'm going to give it the normal 24 hours, but those look perfect.